# How to display Html Entities in High Charts labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display donut-pie from table. Now i'm trying to display pound symbol in the labels, but when I set useHTML to true, i'm losing the point select functionalities.

Additional-Info :

```
allowPointSelect: true,
```

will allow to select segments in chart from the pointers. Here the pointers lose the hover and click events.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the fiddle for it.
[fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5hbpxeL7/2/)

Comment: use labels:{useHTML:true}. Refer: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML

Comment: yes, when i use them, I could be able to see pound symbol, but it loses allowpointselect functions.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you still face issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are already added `useHTML` option. I forked your `JSFiddle` and i'm able to add Euro symbol.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  color: '#3a4570',
  connectorColor: '#ffffff',
  useHTML: true,
  distance: 10,
  style: {
    "fontSize": "11px",
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "textShadow": "false"
  },
  formatter: function() {
    return '<b style="color:#000;font-size:16px;" >'+ this.point.name +'</b><br/><span>Total: </span>&euro;'+
  }
}
```

Forked JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/5hbpxeL7/4/

Comment: Yes, but could you check the point selection is still missing. If you wonder what it is, hover and click the chart labels with and without useHTML.

Comment: Well, Im confused, lets compare two examples: https://jsfiddle.net/ugj49235/ and https://jsfiddle.net/9ej82gm1/, both seem to working in the same way. Could you take a screenshot or descibre in more details what is wrong ?